# Interoperability in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, language-interoperability

I was going through Hadoop and I have 2 questions:

1. How is interoperability achieved in Hadoop
2. Can the Zookeeper work along with the name node in HDFS Master Node and if yes then how is interoperability achieved and how do they interact with the Slave Node?

Comment: Interoperability with/for **what**? What part of Hadoop were you "going through"? I don't understand that question. And do you understand the purpose of Zookeeper in HDFS/YARN? If so, then I think that answers your own question

Comment: I would like to know whether Spark and storm can work together (interoperability) and if yes how is it achieved

Comment: Spark and Storm are independent projects, not core Hadoop, so that's why you need to specify. And if you havent found any resources about Storm and Spark working together already, then that's because (as far as I know) they can perform the same task. Maybe you should research more about it yourself?  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/comprehensive-analysis-data-processing-part-deux-apache-fazelat